# How can I update three tables at the same time?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

There are now three tables that store player information and have exactly the same table structure. How can I update all three tables at the same time?

For example, Change the nationality whose ID is 305 to "AUS" in the one table.

```
UPDATE ATHLETE1
SET CCODE = 'AUS'
WHERE ATHLETEID = 305;
```

How could do this process for three tables(ATHLETE1,ATHLETE2,ATHLETE3) which have same table struct.
Like this:

```
UPDATE ATHLETE1, ATHLETE2, ATHLETE3
SET CCODE = 'AUS'
WHERE ATHLETEID = 305;
```

Comment: Why is athlete 305 stored in three identical tables with the same `ccode` value?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why can't you simply run three UPDATEs in a single transaction? But you should **really** fix your data model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.This is actually a practice in splitting a large data table into three smaller tables and then updating the three smaller tables, so I was wondering if I could update the three tables directly or one by one. This is a practice about SQL so could i do it just by 'update' – caicaicai_Pro 2 secs ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [PL/SQL dynamic query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011):

```
SQL> declare
 v_ccode athlete1.ccode%type := 'AUS';
 v_id    athlete1.athlete_id%type := 305;
begin
 for i in 1..3 loop
   execute immediate 'update athlete'||i||' 
                         set ccode = :code 
                       where athlete_id = :id' using v_ccode,v_id;  
 end loop;
  commit;
end;
/
```

*But note that updating all those three tables is not possible within a single SQL Update statement.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.This is actually an exercise in splitting a large data table into three smaller tables and then updating the three smaller tables, so I was wondering if I could update the three tables directly or one by one. This  is a practice about SQL so could i do it just by 'update'

Comment: I mean could I use 'update' to query and update multiple tables?

Comment: No, that's not possible within a single statement @caicaicai_Pro .

Comment: you too, take care at home :) @xRandom as all we do.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the question of why your data model is like this, the general answer is that you can use a PL/SQL procedure:

```
create or replace procedure set_athlete_country
    ( p_athleteid  athlete1.athleteid%type
    , p_ccode      athlete1.ccode%type )
as
begin
    update athlete1
    set    ccode = p_ccode
    where  athleteid = p_athleteid;

    update athlete2
    set    ccode = p_ccode
    where  athleteid = p_athleteid;

    update athlete3
    set    ccode = p_ccode
    where  athleteid = p_athleteid;

end set_athlete_country;
```

Now you can perform all related changes in a single call that succeeds or fails as a unit.

```
call set_athlete_country(305, 'AUS');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.This is actually an exercise in splitting a large data table into three smaller tables and then updating the three smaller tables, so I was wondering if I could update the three tables directly or one by one. This is a practice about SQL so could i do it just by 'update' – caicaicai_Pro 2 secs ago

Comment: I did wonder whether we could update a `union all` inline view (that is, `update (select ...union all select...) set ccode = 'AUS' where...`) but that gives *ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view*. So unless you create a standalone view and define an `instead of` trigger on it, I think PL/SQL or scripting are the only options.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I think your database design is not good. You should store all the athletes in let's say `Athletes` table and that way you could update all athletes with that id.

So it would be:

```
UPDATE athletes 
SET ccode = 'AUS' 
WHERE athleteid = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.This is actually an exercise in splitting a large data table into three smaller tables and then updating the three smaller tables, so I was wondering if I could update the three tables directly or one by one